# FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Tags: java, android, react-native

```
2022-12-15 17:47:42.350 7215-7254/com.affina.agency E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.affina.agency, PID: 7215
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke PayooSDKAndroidModule.pay
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:192)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147)
        at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:148)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147) 
        at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: EXTERNAL
        at va.n$j0.<init>(Unknown Source:87)
        at va.n$w.b(Unknown Source:27)
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74)
        at va.i.a(Unknown Source:42)
        at va.i.e(Unknown Source:123)
        at va.i.b(Unknown Source:22)
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74)
        at va.b.b(Unknown Source:26)
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74)
        at va.i.a(Unknown Source:42)
        at va.i.e(Unknown Source:123)
        at va.i.b(Unknown Source:22)
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74)
        at va.i.a(Unknown Source:42)
        at va.i.e(Unknown Source:123)
        at va.i.b(Unknown Source:22)
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74)
        at pf.a.d(Unknown Source:6)
        at nf.s.g(Unknown Source:35)
        at nf.s.i(Unknown Source:1)
        at nf.i.e(Unknown Source:4)
        at nf.i.f(Unknown Source:109)
        at nf.t.b(Unknown Source:19)
        at nf.s.d(Unknown Source:24)
        at nf.s$a.invoke(Unknown Source:32)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy8.k(Unknown Source)
        at f.b.k(Unknown Source:7)
        at c.g.a(Unknown Source:12)
        at vn.payoo.paymentsdk.PayooPaymentSDK$Companion.pay(Unknown Source:13)
        at vn.payoo.paymentsdk.PayooPaymentSDK$Companion.pay(Unknown Source:130)
        at vn.payoo.paymentsdk.PayooPaymentSDK.pay(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.affina.agency.PayooSDKAndroidModule.pay(Unknown Source:214)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:148) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147) 
        at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: EXTERNAL
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1604)
        at va.n$j0.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
        at va.n$w.b(Unknown Source:27) 
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74) 
        at va.i.a(Unknown Source:42) 
        at va.i.e(Unknown Source:123) 
        at va.i.b(Unknown Source:22) 
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74) 
        at va.b.b(Unknown Source:26) 
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74) 
        at va.i.a(Unknown Source:42) 
        at va.i.e(Unknown Source:123) 
        at va.i.b(Unknown Source:22) 
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74) 
        at va.i.a(Unknown Source:42) 
        at va.i.e(Unknown Source:123) 
        at va.i.b(Unknown Source:22) 
        at sa.f.k(Unknown Source:74) 
        at pf.a.d(Unknown Source:6) 
        at nf.s.g(Unknown Source:35) 
        at nf.s.i(Unknown Source:1) 
        at nf.i.e(Unknown Source:4) 
        at nf.i.f(Unknown Source:109) 
        at nf.t.b(Unknown Source:19) 
        at nf.s.d(Unknown Source:24) 
        at nf.s$a.invoke(Unknown Source:32) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006) 
        at $Proxy8.k(Unknown Source) 
        at f.b.k(Unknown Source:7) 
        at c.g.a(Unknown Source:12) 
        at vn.payoo.paymentsdk.PayooPaymentSDK$Companion.pay(Unknown Source:13) 
        at vn.payoo.paymentsdk.PayooPaymentSDK$Companion.pay(Unknown Source:130) 
        at vn.payoo.paymentsdk.PayooPaymentSDK.pay(Unknown Source:5) 
        at com.affina.agency.PayooSDKAndroidModule.pay(Unknown Source:214) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:148) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147) 
        at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I added an external library to my React Native application and it worked fine during development, but when I built the release apk, it failed and I still don't have a solution for it.

I tried deleting the gradlew cache and looking at its documentation, but it still didn't work. It still works fine on the development environment, but when I build the release apk, it fails as mentioned above.